# Lookup() in DE with multiple results

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I got a DE with my users in, and a data relationshop to a survey DE with answers from the user. Each user can answer the survey multiple times, and therefor be in the survey DE many time.

Now i want to send a mail with the newest answers data in. If i just a normale Loopup() i will get the first row that matches the user. But it need to get the row with the newest Timestamp on.

```
%%=Lookup("EVALGO","Question_1","email",email)=%%
```

This returns the first rows that matches the email for the user, i need somehow to filter the rows, and return the newest (according to the Timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LookupOrderedRows()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupOrderedRows), specifying your data column DESC.  Then, just select the first item.

Comment: But doesn't that just return a number? "Returns a specified number of rows", I'm not sure how to grap a value from the row returned

Comment: No, you're misreading it.  If you note the second parameter is the number of rows you want back.  It's the "specified number".

Comment: Aah of course :) okay so this 1 row I get you I store in a variable and then I loop through it? Or is it the Field(@row, "question_1") I need to use? Amp script is very new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

this worked:

```
%%[ 

Set @GroupRecords = LookupOrderedRows("EVALGO",0,"Timestamp Asc","email",email))  

If not empty(@GroupRecords) then  
    set @rowcount = Rowcount(@GroupRecords)  
    for @i = 1 to @rowcount  do  
        Set @row = Row(@GroupRecords,@i)  
        Set @TS = Field(@row,"Timestamp")  
        Set @Q1 = Field(@row,"Question_1")  
        Set @Q2 = Field(@row,"Question_2")  
        Set @Q3 = Field(@row,"Question_3")  
        Set @Q4 = Field(@row,"Question_4")  
        Set @Q5 = Field(@row,"Question_5")  
        Set @Average = Field(@row,"Average_score")  
    next @i  

ENDIF 

]%%
```